# how to create custom invitation message to join users in chatroom - smack

Tags: java, xmpp, openfire, smack

I am inviting the offline user to join the group as shown below,

`myChattingRoom.invite("user7@10.10.1.105", "Please join my chatting room");`

Since the invitation message by default, has no body, openfire is not holding the invitation message which needs to be sent to user7 when it comes back online ( as far as I know through my research).

The invitation message currently sending is as below,

```
<message to="user7@10.10.1.105" from="mychattingroom@conference.10.10.1.105"><x xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/muc#user"><invite  from="user1@10.10.1.105"><reason>Please join my chatting room</reason></invite></x><x xmlns="jabber:x:conference" jid="mychattingroom@conference.10.10.1.105"/></message>
```

Now, how do I invite the user with the invitation message containing empty body?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This is my solution using Smack 2.7.7:

```
Message messageWithBody = new Message();
messageWithBody.addBody("", " ");
messageWithBody.setType(Message.Type.normal);
muc.invite(messageWithBody, "user7@10.10.1.105", "Please join my chatting room");
```

Keep in mind that delivery messages with delay has several restrictions so could be not instant when offline users comes online.